# how to apply validation on mobile Number field in React js?

Tags: reactjs, validation

```
<Form.Item label="Phone Number">
            {getFieldDecorator('phone', {
              rules: [
                { 
                  required: true, 
                  message: 'Please input your phone number!' 
                },
              {
                validator: this.validateMobileNumber,
              },
            ],
            })(<Input addonBefore={prefixSelector} style={{ width: '100%' }} />)}
          </Form.Item>
```

Here this component is a antd component and 'validateMobileNumber' is a function where we write the validation logic for mobile number.

```
validateMobileNumber = (callback) => {
      const{ form } = this.props;
      let mnumber = form.getFieldValue('phone');
      console.log("this is a mobil validator",mnumber);
      if(mnumber.length !=10 ){
        console.log("invalid mobile nuumber");
      }

    }
```

here variable 'mnumber' gives the mobile number that user input.

Comment: Can you please explain what you exactly want?

Comment: It's impossible to properly validate phone numbers, you are likely to accidentally block some users. The only correct way is to send an SMS and have them verify the code they receive. If you want to do it in JS then use one of the existing libs for it, they are much better than what you can do but imperfect (and also quite large)

Answer (score 0):

> Form.create will collect and validate form data automatically. But if
>   you don't need this feature or the default behaviour cannot satisfy
>   your business, you can drop Form.create and handle form data manually.

Follow this example and update your code accordingly
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EqagvE?&editable=true&editors=001

```
<Form.Item
  validateStatus={this.state.validateStatus}
  help={this.state.errorMsg}
>
  <InputNumber value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleNumberChange} />
</Form.Item>


handleNumberChange = value => {
  const validateStatus = value.length === 10;
  this.setState({
    validateStatus,
    value,
    errorMsg: isValid ? null : 'Invalid Mobile number'
  });
};
```

Comment: nagesh sanika , thankx men but the code pen link has not any kind of code.

Comment: updated, these are example from antd documentation 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EqagvE?&editable=true&editors=001
 https://codesandbox.io/s/n9c45

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you don't need to call `form.getFieldValue('phone');` in the validator function. Second is the validator accepts 3 parameters where callback is a must. But in your scenario you need to use the value as well so you can do something like

```
validateMobileNumber = (rule, value, callback) => {
  // const{ form } = this.props;
  // let mnumber = form.getFieldValue('phone');
  console.log("this is a mobil validator",value);
  if(value.length !=10 ){
    console.log("invalid mobile nuumber");
  }
 }
```

And if you asking specific validation rule then that really depends on your requirements. Here is the link for others who might be interested in reading the docs as well.
https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-register